# Instaling Rails on Linux Os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, sqlite

I am going through the process of installing Rails on my Linux OS. I have gone through most of the process but it appears something went amiss.
I am using this tutorial:
    http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app

Before things went wrong input to begin the process of adding my changes to Git.

```
[Atlas 02:29 PM] ~/railsbridge/test_app $ git add .
[Atlas 02:30 PM] ~/railsbridge/test_app $ git commit -m "Updates for heroku deployment"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

I then attempted to Push to Heroku

git push heroku master

I recieved what appeared to be an error,

Counting objects: 114, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (100/100), done.
Writing objects: 100% (114/114), 25.08 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 114 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Installing rake 11.2.2
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing minitest 5.9.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.1
remote:        Installing nio4r 1.2.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.1
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
remote:        Installing puma 3.6.0 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_6e2f5dfec8d2bc5e0cc51d96d3f2ae67/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160911-219-equyi.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_6e2f5dfec8d2bc5e0cc51d96d3f2ae67/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_6e2f5dfec8d2bc5e0cc51d96d3f2ae67/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_6e2f5dfec8d2bc5e0cc51d96d3f2ae67/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.0
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.4 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.0.1
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Installing rake 11.2.2
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing minitest 5.9.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.1
remote:        Installing nio4r 1.2.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.1
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
remote:        Installing puma 3.6.0 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
remote:        
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_6e2f5dfec8d2bc5e0cc51d96d3f2ae67/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160911-219-equyi.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_6e2f5dfec8d2bc5e0cc51d96d3f2ae67/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_6e2f5dfec8d2bc5e0cc51d96d3f2ae67/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_6e2f5dfec8d2bc5e0cc51d96d3f2ae67/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.0
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.4 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.0.1
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to infinite-scrubland-38681.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/infinite-scrubland-38681.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/infinite-scrubland-38681.git'


The tutorial tells me the results should look like this


The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (75.101.145.87)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,75.101.145.87' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Counting objects: 60, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Writing objects: 100% (60/60), 79.03 KiB, done.
Total 60 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
       Compiled slug size is 080K
-----> Launching...... done
       App deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:floating-winter-18.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master

Where did I go wrong?
```

I apologize ahead of time if i wasn't detailed enough in my question or violated a site rule. I am completely new here. Thank you in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the sqlite3 gem that cannot be installed on Heroku (I don't know why). This was already solved here:

[Heroku deployment failed because of sqlite3 gem error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083399/heroku-deployment-failed-because-of-sqlite3-gem-error)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i tryed the link. I already tried replacing sqlite in my gemfile with

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

That made no difference

Comment: If you did not run `bundle` you still have sqlite gem in your Gemfile.lock file. You need to run bundle so the changes in your Gemfile would be applied. Than you need to commit these changes before pushing to heroku.