# I can't migrate the database of my Rails app on Heroku with sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sqlite

I'm following [this tutorial](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app) on creating Ruby on Rail apps, and I've hit a roadblock. I am trying to migrate its database to Heroku, only to be told this:

```
c:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>heroku run rails db:migrate
Running rails db:migrate on floating-ocean-40882... up, run.5709 (Free)
rails aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not 
loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the 
minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

I *already* have sqlite3 listed in my Gemfile, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use Heroku, then you need to use the `pg` gem to work with Postgresql instead Sqlite.

Comment: This answer would have been found on Stackoverflow _and_ on [Heroku's documentation site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) if you had searched for it first. Next time, copy the error message and search for it.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku does not support sqlite and it is suggested to use postgresql for production

Please look into the following posts

[Heroku deployment failed because of sqlite3 gem error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083399/heroku-deployment-failed-because-of-sqlite3-gem-error)

[Deploying RoR app to Heroku with Sqlite3 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897431/deploying-ror-app-to-heroku-with-sqlite3-fails)

You can use Postgresql for production and the change should be simple. Just a change of gem in Gemfile and change in database.yml will do.

Answer (score 0):

> Heroku doesn't support SQLite it only support PostgresSQL here is full [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) for deployment on Heroku