# Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile for heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku

Hello guys I do not know why but I am getting this strange error on deployment. I have been spending three hours on this but can not get it to work. It has successfully worked before many times and even work once in the three hours deploying a new app. I do not know why I am getting this error on heroku and only heroku.

**Gemfile**:
[image: gemfile]

**Heroku Error**:
[image: heroku error]

**database.yml**:
[image: database.yml]

If anyone have any suggestions, I am all ears!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku deployment failed because of sqlite3 gem error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083399/heroku-deployment-failed-because-of-sqlite3-gem-error)

Comment: No it does not. I have tried everything that post has specified like changing the gemfiles which and the database.yml worked before numerous of times. I do not know why it is like this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@petertran98 SQLite is a bad fit for running on Heroku. See the official link by heroku [SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#disk-backed-storage) and they recommend using Postgres.

To replace SQLite with Postgres, you need to do the folowwing.

Step - 1: Replace `gem 'sqlite3'` with `gem 'pg'` in your Gemfile.

Step - 2: Replace `adapter: sqlite3` with `adapter: postgresql` in your database.yml.

Now try running the deployment. It should do the trick. If you still face some issue then you might need to do 1 of following things on the basis of what error you see.

Either you need to manually add Postgres if that does no gets created automatically with deployment script.

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql
```

or if you still see the SQLite error then you might need to delete Gemfile.lock file and run `bundle install` command again.

Comment: THANK YOU!  the heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql worked for me. If i wasn't such a newbie at slack I would honor you thanks so much! I do not know why that is a problem I normal never had to manually say "heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql" and it would work .

Comment: @petertran98 can you mark the answer correct so that others can take benefit from it as well.